# In Matlab why do I get "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netinet/in.h': No such file or directory" when compiling mex files?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, compilation, mex

I am using Matlab2015b on windows10 64 bit. I am trying to compile osc mex files with vs2012. I have `liblo.lib` (compiled with VS2010 Ultimate, using [the sources](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rygvnq29nc71bs/osc-mexwin_sources.zip)) and `pthreadVC2.lib` in place and the c source and dll files.

When I compile using: `mex -O -largeArrayDims osc_free_address.c` or `mex -largeArrayDims -I../path/to/liblo-0.27 osc_free_address.c pthreadVC2.lib liblo.lib -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi`

I get the next error message: `"Error using mex osc_free_address.c C:\MATLAB64\extern\include\lo/lo_endian.h(34) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netinet/in.h': No such file or directory`

Can someone please help? I have the mex files already, and they worked with 2015a, but when I downloaded 2015b it gives me the next error: 
`Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Users\Mátyás\Documents\MATLAB\osc_send.mexw64': The specified procedure could not be found. Error in play_Igloo_video (line 6) osc_send(oscAddress, dataPacket)`

but only for the osc_send.mexw64 command, not for any of the other osc commands.
I read that it might because of the different Matlab version and that is why I am trying to compile them again with this version and keep getting the above error. Please help.

Thanks